# Rails escape javascript when rendering form with cocoon fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, cocoon-gem

I'm having a problem when trying to use cocoon nested file upload fields in a form. Form is being submitted via AJAX and then re-rendered with update.js.erb partial.

Here's my partial with an answer and it's edit form:

```
li id="answer_#{answer.id}" class=('accepted' if answer.accepted?)
  div.answer-body
    span
      = answer.body
    ul
      - answer.attachments.each do |a|
        li= link_to a.file.identifier, a.file.url

    - if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == answer.user_id
      = link_to 'Delete answer', [@question, answer], remote: true, method: :delete
      = link_to 'Edit answer', {}, class: "edit-answer", href: '#'
    - if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == @question.user_id && !answer.accepted?
      = link_to 'Accept answer', accept_question_answer_url(@question, answer),
                                                    remote: true, method: :patch, class: 'accept-answer', href: '#'
  div.edit-answer-form.conceal
    = form_for [@question, answer], remote: true do |f|
      = f.label :body, 'Edit answer'
      = f.text_area :body
      div.form-group
        = f.fields_for :attachments do |field|
          = render 'attachment_fields', f: field
        .links
          = link_to_add_association "Moar files!", f, :attachments
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'submit'
      = f.button 'Discard', class: 'discard', type: 'button'
```

It's being completely re-rendered after successful submission.

Here's the `"application/_attachment_fields"` partial:

```
.nested-fields
  .field
    = f.label :file
    = f.file_field :file
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove this attachment", f
```

Cocoon uses an attribute in a `link_to_add` element with a blueprint for a new field. When I submit this form without new files being added everything seems fine. Link looks like this:

```
<a class="add_fields" data-association="attachment" data-associations="attachments" data-association-insertion-template="&lt;div class=&quot;nested-fields&quot;&gt;
      &lt;div class=&quot;field&quot;&gt;
        &lt;label for=&quot;answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments_file&quot;&gt;File&lt;/label&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;file&quot; name=&quot;answer[attachments_attributes][new_attachments][file]&quot; id=&quot;answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments_file&quot; /&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;answer[attachments_attributes][new_attachments][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments__destroy&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;remove_fields dynamic&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Remove this attachment&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;" href="#">Moar files!</a>
```

The problem shows itself when I add new file to the form and submit it. Quotes in the blueprint are not being escaped and I end up with this link:

```
<a class="add_fields" data-association="attachment" data-associations="attachments" data-association-insertion-template="<div class="nested-fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments_file">File</label><input type="file" name="answer[attachments_attributes][new_attachments][file]" id="answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments_file" />
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="answer[attachments_attributes][new_attachments][_destroy]" id="answer_attachments_attributes_new_attachments__destroy" value="false" /><a class="remove_fields dynamic" href="#">Remove this attachment</a>
    </div>" href="#">Moar files!</a>
```

It messes up the whole form and pushes submit and discard buttons out of it making it impossible to submit.

My `update.js.erb` that's being rendered on every form submit:

```
var answer_item = $('#<%= dom_id(@answer) %>');
<% if @answer.errors.any? %>
  answer_item.find('.edit-answer-form').prepend("<%= j render 'shared/error_messages', object: @answer %>");
<% else %>
  answer_item.replaceWith('<%= j(render @answer) %>');
<% end %>
```

I'm sure this is not cocoon's issue, since I was using nested_form gem before and it had similar problem with same concept, it's called blueprint there.

I tried preceding call to `j` with `raw` method, but the problem persists.

I'm confused as hell guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is remoripart [problem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/89).

Solution:

```
<% if remotipart_submitted? %>
  $('.answers-block').append("<%=  j "#{render(@answer)}" %>");
<% else %>
  $('.answers-block').append("<%=  j render(@answer) %>");
<% end %>
```